# Terraform Eventarc Audit Log Trigger

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-run, terraform-provider-gcp, event-arc

I am trying to trigger a Cloud Run service by uploading a file to a Google Cloud Storage bucket. To do so, an Eventarc trigger was created via Terraform, which filters for `storage.objects.create` event from the Audit Logs. Google has documentation on this exact topic: [here](https://cloud.google.com/eventarc/docs/creating-triggers-terraform)

Even though the audit log is correctly recorded, the event is not getting fired (no activity from Eventarc, Pub/Sub, and Cloud Run). I am not sure where else to look.

My question is: Can I still achieve this using Audit Log triggers without relying on direct triggers (e.g., `google.cloud.storage.object.v1.finalized`)?

Truncated output of `gcloud eventarc triggers describe`:

```yaml
destination:
  cloudRun:
    region: us-east4
    service: <SERVICE_NAME>
eventFilters:
- attribute: serviceName
  value: storage.googleapis.com
- attribute: type
  value: google.cloud.audit.log.v1.written
- attribute: methodName
  value: storage.objects.create
name: projects/<PROJECT>/locations/us-east4/triggers/<TRIGGER_NAME>
serviceAccount: <COMPUTE_ENGINE_DEFAULT_SERVICE_ACCOUNT>
transport:
  pubsub:
    subscription: projects/<PROJECT>/subscriptions/eventarc-us-east4-<TRIGGER_NAME>-sub-279
    topic: projects/<PROJECT>/topics/eventarc-us-east4-<TRIGGER_NAME>-401
```

Truncated output of `gcloud logging read "protoPayload.methodName=storage.objects.create" --format=json`:

```json
{
  "logName": "projects/<PROJECT>/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fdata_access",
  "protoPayload": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
    "methodName": "storage.objects.create",
    "resourceName": "projects/_/buckets/<BUCKET>/objects/<BLOB>",
    "serviceData": {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.iam.v1.logging.AuditData",
      "policyDelta": {}
    },
    "serviceName": "storage.googleapis.com",
    "status": {}
  },
  "resource": {
    "labels": {
      "bucket_name": "<BUCKET>",
      "project_id": "<PROJECT>"
    },
    "type": "gcs_bucket"
  },
  "severity": "INFO",
}
```

From GCP Console:
[image: Eventarc Trigger Details Page]

Finally, how I'm creating the Eventarc Trigger with Terraform:

```
resource "google_eventarc_trigger" "cloud_run_trigger" {
    name = "<TRIGGER_NAME>"
    matching_criteria {
        attribute = "type"
        value = "google.cloud.audit.log.v1.written"
    }
    matching_criteria {
        attribute = "serviceName"
        value = "storage.googleapis.com"
    }
    matching_criteria {
        attribute = "methodName"
        value = "storage.objects.create"
    }
    destination {
        cloud_run_service {
            service = google_cloud_run_service.default.name
        }
    }
}
```

I've done everything I can to follow Google's documentation & filter for correct Audit Log based on `serviceName` and `methodName`. The entire project is silent when the event is logged, which seems like the event is not firing for some reason. I do not observe any activity in Cloud Run, Eventarc, and Pub/Sub.